# JQgrid date format in dd-MMM-yyyy

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid

I am using JQgrid and our date is showing in `20-Nov-14` format but I want to display date in `20-Nov-2014` format with sortable propertiy true.

```
{ name: 'DateOfBirth', index: 'DateOfBirth',sortable: true, width: 30, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'd-M-y' } }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use

```
formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'd-M-Y' }
```

with `Y` instead of `y`. By the way jqGrid uses [PHP date format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) in format options.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 formatter: 'date', formatoptions: {srcformat:'d-m-y', newformat: 'd-M-Y'}
```